# ssh sessions disconnect at seemingly random intervals

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Here's the environment:

- Local clients vary between Ubuntu 20, MacOS, Windows
- Server is Ubuntu 18 LTE, problem happens on many different servers
- SSH sessions established via Luminate. More than 1 Luminate gateway is showing this problem.
- Both client and server use keepalive in the ssh config
- It's happening for multiple users in different locations across the globe
- I don't have this problem in other environments (I can stay connected via ssh to other hosts for weeks from my local connection). It's not my network.

Yet, we randomly get kicked out. Sometimes after 20 minutes. Sometimes after 5 hours. But whenever it happens, all tabs (I usually have 6 or 7 of them at the same time) are killed at the same instant. Sometimes in the middle of typing. Inside vi. Inside a psql session. Doesn't matter if it's idle or not.

Luminate admins say they see nothing in the logs.

auth.log on the server just says "pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user"

client says:
"***** ssh exit code == 255 *****
Further debug details: Command 'ssh ...' returned non-zero exit status 255.
Session time was: 2:02:57 (7377 seconds)"

Any ideas what the hell could be going on here?